# Concepts: checking signatures of methods with arguments

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I've been playing around with concepts. Here's a minimal example where I'm trying to create a concept based on method signatures:

```
template<typename T>
concept bool myConcept() {
    return requires(T a, int i) {
        { a.foo()   } -> int;
        { a.bar(i)  } -> int;
    };
}

struct Object {
    int foo()    {return 0;}
    int bar(int) {return 0;}
};

static_assert(myConcept<Object>(), "Object does not adhere to myConcept");
```

To my surprise writing `{ a.bar(int) } -> int` did not work, so I resorted to adding an additional argument to the `requires` expression. This seems a bit strange and I was wondering if there is a way to do the same thing. Another thing that worked was using something like `{ a.bar((int)0) } -> int`, but I find this worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concepts check expressions, and `a.bar(int)` is not one. By writing

```
{ a.foo(int) } -> int
```

you ask the compiler to check that the aforementioned expression has type `int`. Which doesn't make sense.

You did find a valid alternative; another one might be, since the type of `a.bar(x)` doesn't depend on `x`' value:

```
template<typename T>
concept bool myConcept() {
    return requires(T a) {
        { a.foo()   } -> int;
        { a.bar(0)  } -> int;
    };
}

struct Object {
    int foo()    {return 0;}
    int bar(int) {return 0;}
};

static_assert(myConcept<Object>(), "Object does not adhere to myConcept");
```

Answer (score 6):

As actual value of the type doesn't matter, I'd suggest using `int{}` as argument. This documents the purpose of the argument somewhat better, IMO:

```
{ a.bar(int{})  } -> int;
```

Obviously this won't work with types for which there is no default constructor. In templates, one would use [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) to work around similar issue, but here GCC errors:

```
error: static assertion failed: declval() must not be used!
```

But there is nothing to stop us from writing equivalent (but unimplemented) function to be used with concepts, like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type makeval();

template<typename T>
concept bool myConcept() {
    return requires(T a, int i) {
        { a.foo() } -> int;
        { a.bar(makeval<int>()) } -> int;
    };
}

struct Object {
    int foo()    {return 0;}
    int bar(int) {return 0;}
};

static_assert(myConcept<Object>(), "Object does not adhere to myConcept");
```

Comment: I like you're makeval<T>() and I'd like to see it in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

6+ years later this question is still relevant but the syntax seem to have changed.

```
template<typename T>
concept bool myConcept() {
    return requires(T a) {
        { a.foo()   } -> int;
        { a.bar(0)  } -> int;
    };
}
```

Fail with:

```
warning: the 'bool' keyword is not allowed in a C++20 concept definition
    9 | concept bool myConcept() {
      |         ^~~~
In function 'concept bool myConcept()':
error: return-type-requirement is not a type-constraint
   11 |         { a.foo()   } -> int;
      |                          ^~~
error: return-type-requirement is not a type-constraint
   12 |         { a.bar(0)  } -> int;
```

demo : [fail build](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eU4aikgkCIdCzq0u)

With the 2a/2b syntax (checked with g++12 and clang 17) :

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept  myConcept =  requires(T a) { // no bool, no () after myConcept no {} after = 
        { a.foo()   } -> std::convertible_to<int>; // if we need convertibility
        { a.bar(0)  } -> std::same_as<int>;        // if we need exact type
    };

struct Object {
    int foo()    {return 0;}
    int bar(int) {return 0;}
};

// no () after myConcept<Object>
static_assert(myConcept<Object>, "Object does not adhere to myConcept");
            
int main(){}
```

[Demo on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/g3JDIS8Ko8dJRrgd)

If we change `int bar(int) {return 0;}` to  `double bar(int) {return 0;}` the `static_assert` fail with:

```
error: static assertion failed: Object does not adhere to myConcept
   20 | static_assert(myConcept<Object>, "Object does not adhere to myConcept");
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: because 'Object' does not satisfy 'myConcept'
note: because type constraint 'std::same_as<double, int>' was not satisfied:
   11 |         { a.bar(0)  } -> std::same_as<int>;        // if we need exact type
      |                          ^
[...]/same_as.h:29:19: note: because '__same_as_impl<double, int>' evaluated to false
   29 | concept same_as = __same_as_impl<_Tp, _Up> && __same_as_impl<_Up, _Tp>;
      |                   ^
/[...]/same_as.h:26:26: note: because '_IsSame<double, int>::value' evaluated to false
   26 | concept __same_as_impl = _IsSame<_Tp, _Up>::value;
```

As expected!

Source: [Can't make C++20 concept requiring bool member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62283582/cant-make-c20-concept-requiring-bool-member-function)