# Can't make C++20 concept requiring bool member function

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

This MCVE is giving trouble in both Visual Studio (2019, with the C++20 flag on) and g++10 (also, with C++20 option set). The complaint in each case is that `bool` is not a type constraint. (So what should I be typing to require that a given type have such a member function?)

```
#include <concepts> 

template <typename T>
concept testable = requires(T t)
{
    { t.foo() } -> bool; //Error is here: "expected a concept" or
                         //  "return-type-requirement is not a type-constraint"
};

class A
{
public:
    bool foo() const { return true; }
};

template<testable T>
void verify(const T& t) { assert(t.foo()); }

int main(void)
{
    A a; verify(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept needs to be written as:

```
template <typename T>
concept testable = requires(T t)
{
    { t.foo() } -> std::convertible_to<bool>; 
};
```

Note that this is actually more explicit in the constraints for `foo`. It says, calling `foo` must return a type that is *convertible to* a `bool`.

This means you can also specify that the return should be *exactly* a `bool`, if that's what you want:

```
template <typename T>
concept testable = requires(T t)
{
    { t.foo() } -> std::same_as<bool>; 
};
```

Comment: How would you do that? Looks like that's what the OP tried and it didn't work.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings added an example.